# Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a one to one function and $A \subseteq X$ then $Y - f(A) \subseteq f(X-A)$. Am I on the right track?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a one to one function and $A \subseteq X.$  $A, X, Y$, are all sets.

I am trying to decipher if the following statements are true or false.  If true I will need to prove it and if false I must give a counterexample.

1. Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a one to one function and $A \subseteq X$ then $f(X -A) \subseteq Y - f(A)$.
2. Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a one to one function and $A \subseteq X$ then $Y - f(A) \subseteq f(X-A)$.

Here is the example I came up with it $f: N \rightarrow N$ be the function given by $f(x)= x^2$. 
Let $X=[0,4] A=[1,3] Y=[0,16]$
then $f(A)=[1,9]$
so $Y- f(A)= [0,1] \cup [9,16] $ and $f(X-A)= [0,16]$

so

1. $[0,16] \subseteq [0,1] \cup [9,16] $
2. $[0,1] \cup [9,16] \subseteq [0,16]$

So the first would be true and the second would be false? Am I on the right track?

Comment: I think you are right. The second statement is not true because there can be elements in $Y-f(A)$ that are not the image of anybody in $X$. That is, $f$ needs not be onto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is true. The second is true only if $f$ is onto.

Proof:

$1)$ Let $y$ $\in f(X - A)$, then $\exists$ $x \in X - A$ such that $y = f(x)$. But, $x \in X - A$, so $x \notin A$. If $y \in f(A)$, then $\exists$ $a \in A$ such that $y = f(a)$. But $f$ is one-to-one. So, as $f(x) = f(a)$, we get $x = a$. This means that $x \in A$. A contradiction. Therefore, $y \in Y - f(A)$.

As $y$ was arbitrary, we get $f(X - A) \subset Y - f(A)$

$2)$ Let $f: X = \{1,2\} \longrightarrow Y = \{10,20,30\}$ be defined:

$f(1) = 10$; $f(2) = 20$

$f$ is a one-to-one mapping.

Let $A = \{1\}$. Then, $f(A) = \{10\}$ and $f(X - A) = f(\{2\}) = \{20\}$.

$30 \in Y - f(A)$, but $30 \notin f(X - A)$.

Comment: Can this proof work if the function is only onto?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, $Y-f(A)=[0,1)\cup{(9,16]}$ (note: the end points $1$ and $9$ are not in this set).
However, you have miscalculated on the second one:

$f(X-A)=f([0,1)\cup{(3,4]) = [0,1]\cup{(9,16)}}$

However, you seem to have drawn the right conclusion, so maybe just a typo?

Anyway, here's a sketch of how you can prove it:
Suppose that $y$ is an element of $f(X-A)$. This means that $y=f(x)$ for some $x$ that is not in $A$. Can you now explain this means $y\in{Y-f(A)}$ And why this fact means that statement number one is true?

Answer (score 0):

> First show that if $f:X\to Y$ is injective and $A\subseteq X$ then  $f(X)\setminus f(A)= f(X\setminus A)$.

Let $f(x)\in f(X)\setminus f(A)$ then $f(x)\in f(X)$ but $f(x)\notin f(A)$. So there is a $x_1\in X$ such that $f(x)=f(x_1)$ but $x_1\notin A$ $\left( \text{as}\,\,  x_1\in A\implies f(x)=f(x_1)\in f(A)\right)$. Hence $f(x)=f(x_1)$ for some $x_1\in X\setminus A$ i.e. $f(x)\in f(X\setminus A)$. Thus $f(X)\setminus f(A)\subseteq f(X\setminus A)$.

For the other direction, let $f(x)\in f(X\setminus A)$. So $f(x)=f(y)$ with $y\in X\setminus A$. By injectivity of $f$, $x=y$ and hence $x\notin A$ i.e. $f(x)\in f(X)$ and $f(x)\notin f(A)$. Thus $f(x)\in f(X)\setminus f(A)$. So the proof is complete.

From this, it follows that if $f(X)=Y$ (i.e if $f$ is surjective) then $Y\setminus f(A)= f(X\setminus A)$. Since in general $f(X)\subseteq Y$, so we can say that if $f$ is injective then $f(X\setminus A)=f(X)\setminus f(A)\subseteq Y\setminus f(A)$. So if you choose a function which is not surjective then the reverse inclusion need not hold.

For example consider the injective function $f:X \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$, where $X=\{0,1\}$. Then if $A=\{0\}$ then $\Bbb R\setminus f(A)=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\not \subseteq \{1\}=f(\{1\})=f(X\setminus A)$.